# Can an XSD schema have different conditions based on whether multiple elements exist?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The XML document design I'm working on has a couple conditions:

**If one ColorMap element exists:**

`<ColorMap>no attributes needed</ColorMap>`

**If more than one ColorMap element exists:**

`<Colormap version="1.0" default="true">Both these attributes are required</ColorMap>`

Is there a way I can create an XSD schema that will validate this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, XSD 1.0 cannot constrain the requiredness of attributes based upon the count of elements present.  You'll have to redesign your XML or perform such a check outside of XSD.

In XSD 1.1 you could express such a constraint using `xs:assertion`.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions is where you'll find more info. The most important thing to keep in mind is that XSD 1.1 assertions are XPath expressions, which means that they are very rich in expressivity.